# How to print out an int value in a class?

Tags: python

I am currently learning to create a class in python. I put in an `int` value in and it doesn't seem to print out the `int` value at all. Is there something I am doing wrong? 
This is my current code:

```
class Cars:
    def __init__ (self, model, Type, price):
        self.model  = 'Model:'+ model
        self.Type= 'Type:'+ Type
        self.price= price

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.model, self.Type)

    def Price(self):
        return 'Price:'.format(self.price)


car_1= Cars('CLA','Coupe', 34000)
car_2= Cars('GLA','SUV', 38000)

print(Cars.fullname(car_1))
print(car_1.Price())
print(car_2.fullname())
print(car_2.Price())
```

Output:

```
Model:CLA Type:Coupe
Price:
Model:GLA Type:SUV
Price:
```

I want to print out the price value under `Price`.

If there is anyone that can help, I would appreciate it. If there is a link to a similar question, please link if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `{}`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter

```
def Price(self):
    return 'Price: {}'.format(self.price)
```

Moreover, you are naming a method (`Price`) very similar to a member (`price`).

- If you want to tell the class to print the value, you should call the method something like `printPrice`. It's good practice to name methods by something that describes an action.
- If you just want to get the member, use `<object>.<member>`.
- If you really need to do something with the member before returning it, that is, you want to hide the inner workings of the class to the outside, then use [Properties or Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=getter#id1). But that's more advanced and should only be use if really needed.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. Thanks. I shall keep it in mind.